# How to add view inside Tab Bar Controller Storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard

I am new to Storyboard. I've a `Tab Bar Controller` and I want to create a View Controller which include the `Tab Bar Controller` in the view. I have did that but it didn't work. I have read a lot of topics but I couldn't find what I want.

[image: I hope this picture display what I want]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Container View** and embed UITabBarController with it. Looks like this:
[image]

Comment: No, I'm trying to show a view on the `Tab Bar Controller` and I don't want to show the first selected tab.

Comment: His answer kind of work. You can add new View Controller to your storyboard and then add a Container to it. Then add a segue (embed) from the Container to the Tab Bar Controller.  Now you can add other views above the Container (which has the Tab Bar Controller), so in the end, you are adding objects above the Tab Bar Controller.